# Hide sibling <ul>s when

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This should be unbelievably easy, but after almost an hour of researching I haven't found an answer that exactly fits my needs.  I have a dropdown menu with submenus and sub-sub-menus, and I am trying to code it so that when one `<li>` is clicked (to show its child `<ul>`), all of the other sibling `<ul>`'s close (as you would expect with any nav menu).  This is one of the pieces of code I have tried that is not exhibiting the desired behavior (sibling submenus do not disappear):

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Go to first item</a>
        <ul>1st item!</ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Go to second item</a>
        <ul>2nd item!</ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Go to third item</a>
        <ul>3rd item!</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('li').click(function() { $("ul ul:visible").hide(); });
```

Please let me know if there is an issue with my JavaScript as I am fairly new to it.

EDIT:  While there are several helpful fixes to my JavaScript below, somebody provided an extremely simple way to accomplish this in plain CSS with no JavaScript at all, and that is such a simple and universal fix for anyone with a similar problem that I have decided to mark that one as the Best Answer.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: It would be helpful if you can create a [stack snippet](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in your question to demonstrate what you've tried and what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain CSS to accomplish this:

```css
ul a:focus ~ ul, ul ul:hover {
  display: block;
}
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Go to first item</a>
    <ul>1st item!</ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Go to second item</a>
    <ul>2nd item!</ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Go to third item</a>
    <ul>3rd item!</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, this is even easier than I thought!  I hadn't even considered a plain CSS approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you hide all the `ul` elements and display only the child `ul`

```
$('li').click(function() { 
   $("ul ul").hide();
   $("ul", this).show();
});
```

Comment: For further reference, see [Selector Context @ jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are almost there.  All you need to do is fine the `ul` that is currently under the clicked `li` and display it.

```js
$('li').click(function() { 
    $("ul ul:visible").hide();
    $(this).find('ul').show();
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $('ul');
    if( !container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0 ) {
        container.find('ul:visible').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Go to first item</a>
        <ul>1st item!</ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Go to second item</a>
        <ul>2nd item!</ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Go to third item</a>
        <ul>3rd item!</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:** I have updated the code to include a 'click off' function so when a user clicks entirely outside of the original `parent ul`, the menu as a whole will close.

Comment: This continues to display the menu after the user clicks away

Comment: @Pluto Although I do not see this as a request by the OP, I have added the functionality.